# Changing connection string on a wrapped-to-exe jar file for client-server

Tags: java, jdbc, client-server

I'm working on a project which sooner or later will be deployed. I just have a question about setting and saving the connection string's ip address when a Jar or exe is installed on client PCs.

Let's say I have

```
public class DBUtil {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/enrollmentdb";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";

     public static Connection getConnection(DBType dbType) throws SQLException
     {
         return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
     }

     public static void processException(SQLException ex){
         System.err.println("Error message: "+ex.getMessage());
         System.err.println("Error code: "+ex.getErrorCode());
         System.err.println("SQL State: "+ex.getSQLState());
     }
}
```

The `192.168.0.1` ip address is different on every PC. I want the application to run on any PC so I thought I'd create a GUI to provide fields to set it's IP Address on first run of application but how can I change and permanently save it on a wrapped `.exe` Java file. A user may want to use the application on another PC by copying and pasting the application folder with its binaries, that will require a form to change the IP Address and save it so that he or she don't have to set it everytime and don't have to call on us.

How do I set it so that it can be updated anytime?

Should I create a text file and write the new Ip Address and retrieve from the text file when application is initialized and run?

Any other better suggestions?
I'd appreciate any examples.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA doesn't allow you to save configurations into .jar or .exe. But you can save your data in a .ini/.properties file. You will read it each time you run the application. And your user can easily update value from .ini/.properties file.

See: [Write and read .properties in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)